# Posting variable to hidden field is not updating in php

Tags: php, post, get, request, hidden-field

i have find out the solution just added onclick in submit button update value in hidden field.As i get hidden field value the pagenation is getting displayed and in pagination anchor i have used to display pagination as i onclick the pagin() the page number passed to pagin function in which i used ajax to post pageno and limits problem is i am get ajax data of limits by $_POST['limits'] but cant get value of pageno as i used $_POST['pageno'] why?

```
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
echo '<td id="'.$i.'"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pagenav" id="but'.$i.'"  style="cursor: hand;cursor: pointer;font-size:18px" onclick="javascript: pagin('.$i.'); ">'.$i.'</a></td>';} 



<script>
            function pagin(value){
    var f = document.getElementById('pageno').value="";
var option = document.getElementById('mydisplaylimits').value="";
var limits = document.getElementById('limits').value;
var pageno = document.getElementById('pageno').value = +value;

        $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "page.php",
  data: {
       limits: limits,
 pageno: pageno
    },
  success: function() {


  } 
});
    }
    //-->
    </script>


<form action="page.php" method="post" id="pagination" name="pagination">
    <input type="HIDDEN" value=""  id ="limits" name="limits">
    <input type="HIDDEN" id="pageno" value="" name="pageno">
    <select style="border: 2px outset rgb(204, 51, 0);" size="1" name="mydisplaylimit" id="mydisplaylimit" >
    <option value="5" selected="selected" id="mydisplaylimits"  >5</option>
    <option value="10" id="mydisplaylimits"  value="10" >10</option>
    <option value="20"  id="mydisplaylimits"  >20</option>
    <option value="50" id="mydisplaylimits"    >50</option>
    </select><input type="SUBMIT" value="GO"  style="border: 2px outset rgb(204, 51, 0);" class="form_enter" onclick="$('#limits').val($('#mydisplaylimit').val())"></form>
```

Comment: If you want to post without refreshing you have to use AJAX. BTW, IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple elements with `id="mydisplaylimits"`.

Comment: Indeed, in fact I have never seen the ID field in a selects "option" and I am pretty sure option doesn't even support the id field although I could be mistaken.  Plus, the question is quite difficult to understand.

Comment: @Barmar i used  var pageno = document.pagination.pageno.value =+value;
  document.pagination.submit(); but it submits the drop down default value with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the hidden input. Just set the default option in the `<select>` to the value that was posted.

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" id="pagination" name="pagination">
    <input type="HIDDEN" id="pageno" value="" name="pageno">
    <select style="border: 2px outset rgb(204, 51, 0);" size="1" name="mydisplaylimit" id="mydisplaylimit">
<?php
$default_limit = isset($_POST['mydisplaylimit']) ? $_POST['mydisplaylimit'] : 5;
foreach (array(5, 10, 20, 50) as $option) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option ?>" <? if($option == $default_limit) { echo "selected"; } ?> >
    <?php
}
?>
    </select>
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="GO"  style="border: 2px outset rgb(204, 51, 0);" class="form_enter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what your question is asking. I've taken your code however and tidied it up some.  I'm sure there are more improvements that could easily be made.

Move this to head HEAD area of your page instead of the body.

```
<?php
if isset($_POST['mydisplaylimit'])) {
    $mydisplaylimit = $_POST['mydisplaylimit'];
}
else {
    $mydisplaylimit = "some default value";
}
?>
```

Your form should look like this now.

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" id="pagination" name="pagination">
    <input type="HIDDEN" value="<?php echo $mydisplaylimit;?>" id="limits" name="limits">
    <input type="HIDDEN" id="pageno" value="" name="pageno">
    <select style="border: 2px outset rgb(204, 51, 0);" size="1" name="mydisplaylimit" id="mydisplaylimit">
    <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="GO"  style="border: 2px outset rgb(204, 51, 0);" class="form_enter">
 </form>
```

Comment: as i submit the form and get value of hidden field as $_post['limits'] it shows zero in var_dump as i press submit button form for second time its getting the value.yes i have even tried above method the result are same tremor

Comment: When you open the page for the first time, there are no values in `$_POST` because you haven't submitted the form yet. So nothing gets put into the hidden field until AFTER you submit the first time.

Comment: @Barmar  so how can i get value at first submission? i have used  onchange="$('#limits').val($('#mydisplaylimit').val()) in select and it gets updated  but the problem is default value is not getting updated in hidden filed, because we have used onchange method in select.my doubt is how to get default value of drop down box.sorry for bad english

Comment: If you start a new question with that, I'll post an answer. I'm not going to post it here, since it's not an answer to this question.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873347/set-the-default-value-of-drop-down-list-with-the-last-value-choosen